# Migrating from Xamarin to Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, web, ionic-framework, camera, progressive-web-apps

So we have an application in production running on both Apple store and Google Play store. We originally built it on Xamarin and hope to port it to a newer infrastructure. We looked at some avenues such as Ionic + Angular with a backend to MongoDB Realm. Our biggest concern for frontend capabilities have been offline data support, image editor, and barcode scanning. We are hoping to go to a Progressive Web App this time and not have to deal with the stores. In our recent research, we found Camera and Permission API's on browsers is lacking, especially iOS (Steve would be upset if he was alive). Recently we noticed Flutter is growing fast and web support is getting better, though their camera API's for iOS and some Androids still have issues. Ionic's camera support is not perfect but seems to be solid compared to Flutter. Anyone else having issues with camera API support (especially Flutter)?  We would like to have a stable camera/permissions on the web if possible but we feel the timing may not be right. Would like to hear others and their thoughts and thank you for your time!

Comment: FWIW I've had no issues with camera on iOS/Android with Ionic. If you just want the user to be able to quickly take pictures or import photos from their camera roll, you can literally just use an `<input type="file" />` -- no plugins required, very simple.

Comment: Thanks @Nisala We also need photo edit capabilities and see there are many plugins for ionic for this. Ionic seems to be the choice